# How to add navigateurl to hyperlink in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Every row in my gridview is supposed to have a button/hyperlink that navigates to Page?id=**something**
Then there's javascript that catches the redirect and prints the page as an iframe.
This **something** is and already available in the row (but hidden).
So i'd want to do something like NavigateUrl = "~/Page.aspx?id=" + Id.ToString() for each field, but the thing is the Id is populated in DataBind() from a LINQ datasource.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridleitNidurstada" runat="server" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True"
    CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="gridLeit_RowDataBound"
    AllowSorting="True" SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc-header" SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc-header"
    OnSorting="gridleitNidurstada_Sorting" CurrentSortField="Id" CurrentSortDir="Ascending"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" Visible="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Print" Text="Print" **anything here?**/>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc-header"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc-header"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

Binding is something like this: Could i do it there?
Or in the rowbound event?

```
IQueryable<model.SomeClass> someClass = 
    from m in preparePredicate()
    select new model.SomeClass
    {
        Id = m.id,
        ...
    };
        gridleitNidurstada.DataSource = someClass;
        gridleitNidurstada.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="col1,col2" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="gotopage.aspx?p1={0}&p2={1}" Text="Print">
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlfields.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring) on MSDN.

EDIT:

---

If you don't know the exact url when creating the grid, you'll have to do a bit more work.
An example I've worked on this week, using an itemtemplate. But in order to use this, you have to set `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks` to `false`. And do some extra work in code behind for this.
I've only used paging on my grid, so this sample I can provide.
Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridViewTicketsClosed" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
    GridLines="None" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="gridViewTicketsClosed_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewPageIndexChanging">
    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketId" HeaderText="Nr.">
            <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateStarted" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="President" HeaderText="President">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketTypeId" HeaderText="TicketType"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkActionLog" runat="server" Text="Log"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void gridViewTicketsClosed_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var hyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("lnkActionLog") as HyperLink;
        if (hyperLink != null)
            hyperLink.NavigateUrl = CreateShowActionLogUrl(e.Row) + "?id="+ DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TicketId");
    }
}
```

Comment: After re-reading your question I think you're settled with the first suggestion I made, since your url will always be the same. Only the value of the queryparameter is different.

Comment: yeah thanks this was exactly what i needed for this case, but your edit actually helped with a follow-up idea.

Answer (score 7):

Include following in your `NavigateUrl` attribute

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Sl_no", 
              "frmAddIntake.aspx?id=Dashboard&intake_id={0}") %>'
```

Comment: Rupesh More solution ,, worked for me , but was needed to bind the <SL_no> to hidden column first not the data bind from datasource directly ,, thanks dude..

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Id" ItemStyle-Width="30">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("TheQueryStringParameterComingFromDB", "~/PageYouWantTONavigateTo.aspx?Id={0}") %>'
                    Text='GiveTextYouWantToDisplay' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply works for me. Nothing else required.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                        Text="URL Text" NavigateUrl='<%# "URL.aspx?your_parameter=" + Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```